# PHP optimizing queries in customer class

Tags: php, mysql, class, optimization, pdo

I have class *Customer* which contains all functions that are linked to customers. There I have `function info($column)` which does simple `SELECT` query to table *customers*.

In my system there are page showing all customer info and every field has `$customer->info('fieldname')` code which selects the info from database. So every field has separated query, hasn't it?

Is there any way to do mass `SELECT` with class with only one `SELECT * FROM customers` query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just have a function called `__construct()` that runs `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id=?` query and populates class properties.

And then make `info()` function just return value of corresponding property.

Or you can address the property directly, calling `$customer->name` instead of `$customer->info('name')`

Comment: I have three parameters in `info()` function. They are `$var` (which means column name), `$customerid` (if this is null, default is `$_GET['id']`) and `$clear` (true or false (default)... as false it prints `-` if the field is empty, as true it prints nothing). How to use these parameters if using `__construct()`?

Comment: Or may I do only one class for customer infos? And other for creating, editing or deleting customers..?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.